# How to add multiple adapters to single listview android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have added 2 adapters to single view to show single suggestions list and after getting the result with different list.Iam not interested to create 2 listviews inside the single acitivity.Need to modify the adapters only.

Example :

```
wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.listItem, matchedWordsList));
```

after doing something need to chage the same list view with another adapter

```
wordsList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, mList));
```

I have written this step within the handler ,giving me the following error

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

I knew the error.But my question is --- is it ok to add multiple adapters to single listview?Please give me code snippet on this if any.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code in your handler

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

      wordsList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, mList));

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that and the content from the first adapter will be replaced by the content from the second adapter. Your error is not related to the fact that you are setting multiple adapters